# DateTime in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, knockout.js, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am having issue displaying (C#) DateTime / (LocalDB) Date type correctly in my front-end using a code-first Entity Framework approach.

`StudentDetailsDTO` model class:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
[Column(TypeName = "Date"), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
public string SID { get; set; }
public string Course { get; set; }
public string GroupName { get; set; }
public string Specialty { get; set; }
```

The column `BirthDate` works correctly. It returns date (without time) in the provided format as a form of replacement for `DateTime` in the table.

However, in the front-end it is still displayed along with the T attribute in [Details table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWAWs.png) for particular student, as if `Date` type in the column had no effect.

If I were to use `string` data type instead, there would be no issues. However, I am trying my best to stick to appropriate data types convention.

Do I need to change something in the controller? HTML view? Or maybe in Knockout.js? I've tried some solutions provided here on Stackoverflow, but they either didn't work or I had trouble implementing them.

I am a complete newbie and lost. Such a little change, so many problems.
I would be grateful for every possible hint or solution. Thank you for your time.

Comment: DateTime does not store the date in any format. And it always stores both date and time. So you need to format it in your frontend

Answer (score 1):

you must decorate BirthDate with DataType attribute to make it work.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime BirthDate { set; get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are rendering the Date.

In razor you can use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BirthDate)
```

or if you are using Knockout to render the date, you could consider [moment.js](https://momentjs.com) and you'd just replace the date with the birth date from you View Model.

```
moment('2013-01-01T00:00:00.000').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```